# is there another way to separate a process from php exec?

Tags: php

I've been at this for a few days now on and off while working on other sections of  my project

```
echo "playing";
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
exec('./omx-start.sh "' . $full . '" > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
die();
```

I've also put the exec in my die like:

```
die(exec('nohup ./omx-start.sh "' . $full . '" > /dev/null 2>&1 &'));
```

I've also tried adding nohup (like above)

content of omx-start.sh

```
ps cax | grep "omxplayer" > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    sudo killall omxplayer && sudo killall omxplayer.bin
fi
echo $1
if [ -e "playing" ]
then
    rm "playing"
fi
mkfifo "playing"

nohup omxplayer -b -o hdmi "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

also I've added nohup and & at by the control operator 
it SHOULD fork off into subshell 
I can do this easily with python, with any other language actually. 
I am almost going to have to make my php script call a python script that runs the omx-start.sh script too? or is there actually a good way to fork php scripts or force them to stop loading?

My `die();` SOMETIMES triggers as well if I do die("test"); I can see it, sometimes triggering. and the page STILL is hanging (loading) but the php process is freed up to take other request at that time.. but the page.. still.. hangs.. what?